# Datastax Sqoop migration issue from sybase to cassandra

Tags: cassandra, sybase, datastax, sqoop

I am using below command to migrate Image data from Sybase ASE to Datastax cassandra to move single table.

```
sudo ./bin/dse sqoop cql-import --connect  

jdbc:sybase:Tds:XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXXX/db_name?ServiceName=master --username 

user --table TableName --cassandra-username cassandra_username --cassandra-

password cassandra_password --driver com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver --verbose -

-cassandra-keyspace DocumentWareHouse --cassandra-table CASS_TABLENAME --

cassandra-host XX.XX.XX.XX -P
```

Below error I am facing

```
Hadoop functionality is deprecated and may be removed in a future release.
Enter password: 
WARN  18:08:24,632 Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
Note: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/c684cdecc9821139dc090e4a6eb1827b/DispatchDocumentType.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
WARN  18:08:33,235 Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ERROR 18:08:33,418 PriviledgedActionException as:root cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory DispatchDocumentType already exists
ERROR 18:08:33,419 Encountered IOException running import job: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory DispatchDocumentType already exists
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:887)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:186)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:159)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:247)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:665)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:601)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:57)
```

I would appreciate if someone could assist, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly mentioned in the error:

> Output directory DispatchDocumentType already exists

Remove this directory and try. It should work.

Comment: Thank you, but no such directory is there.

Comment: I am looking cassandra directory. I need to migrate data from sybase to cassandra. Thanks again.